# combineLatest to 2 separate json objects

Tags: angular, firebase, rxjs, reactive-programming, google-cloud-firestore

Is it possible to change the index of combineLatest ? the results I get are an array with the index [0] and [1] from combining the 2 observables. I want to convert this to json so that I can write it back to another record but change the index [0] to sender: {..data..data} and index [1] to an object also

```
  returnUser(receivingUser, activeUser)  {
    const rUsr = this.db.doc<iUser>(`users/${receivingUser}`).valueChanges()

    const aUsr = this.db.doc<iUser>(`users/${activeUser}`).valueChanges()  

    return Observable.combineLatest([aUsr, rUsr]).map(response => {
      console.log("map",response);
      return response;
    })

  }
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can do for example this:

```
return Observable.combineLatest(aUsr, rUsr, (res1, res2) => ({
  sender: res1,
  object: res2,
}));
```

Comment: I followed this exact example and cant replicate the solution. Please can you tell me where I am going wrong here. let result = Observable.combineLatest(tempArray[0],tempArray[1],(res1,res2)=>
                      ({
                         sender:res1
                         
                  }))
                  
                  result.subscribe((res:any)=>
                  {
                      debugger;
                  })